# show selected listview row image to next activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

I am able to send selected listview text to another activity using xml parsing, but not able to fetch selected image to next activity, here I am placing my code, please find out the reason why I am not getting image to another activity:-

MainActivity Code:-

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,

                            int position, long id) {

                          HashMap<String, String> map = pizzaList.get(position);

               Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

                     in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));

                       in.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, map.get(KEY_DESCRIPTION));    

                        in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, map.get(KEY_THUMB_URL));

                       in.putExtra(KEY_COST, map.get(KEY_COST));
                        startActivity(in);
                    }

                });
```

SecondActivity Code:-

```
Intent in = getIntent();



   final String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);

   final String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION);

   final String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL);

   final String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);



   TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);

   TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_description);

  TextView cost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_cost);

   ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
   ImageView thumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image);

title.setText(title);
description.setText(description);
cost.setText(cost);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, thumb);
```

Comment: need to add full code missing data type witch data send to activity

Answer (score 0):

```
final String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
final String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
final String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL);
log.i("log_tag","Image URl:"+thumb_url);
final String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);



 TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);

 TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_description);

 TextView cost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_cost);


 ImageView thumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image);

 title.setText(title);
description.setText(description);
 cost.setText(cost);
 Drawable d = LoadImageFromWebOperations(ImageUrl);
  imageView.setImageDrawable(d);   




     public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: code only answers aren't welcome here. Please add some description and explanations to your answer.

Comment: when u select item at that time get your item image url and use this url to next activity

Comment: use this ans check do u get image url or not  final String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL);
            log.i("log_tag","Image URl:"+thumb_url);

Comment: OK Buddy. i will try this, and then revert you ok.

Comment: Amit Ji, i have done, by using my old code itself, brother you will laugh, because i did very small mistake, see line below, which i was using earlier :- final String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL);  and now i have tried with :- final String imageUri = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL); because i am using this variable:- static final String KEY_THUMBURL = "imageUri";  but i really appreciate your support which you have given me...thanks brother

Comment: @AmitPrajapati you should explain it with more than a sentence in the answer, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think  your `KEY_THUMB_URL` is your url just call this method in your second Activity this is return a bitmap then this bitmap set you on your image view

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String imgPath) {

        String imgUrlStr = imgPath ;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {   
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imgUrlStr).getContent()); 
        }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: ok, jeetu i will try this then get back to you, for now thanks to reply

Comment: Jeetu Ji, i have done, by using my old code itself, brother you will laugh, because i did very small mistake, see line below, which i was using earlier :- final String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL);  and now i have tried with :- final String imageUri = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL); because i am using this variable:- static final String KEY_THUMBURL = "imageUri";  but i really appreciate your support which you have given me...thanks brother

Comment: yes but how did you set the image to imageview ? @Sam

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why I was not getting an image into next activity.
I did very small mistake, see line below, which I was using earlier :

```
 final String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL);
```

And now I have tried with:

```
final String imageUri = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMBURL);
```

Because I am using this variable:

```
static final String KEY_THUMBURL = "imageUri";
```